# Binding a number to angular routerLink is showing strange behaviour

Tags: angular, url, url-routing, angular2-routing

In Angular v16, when binding a number to routerLink the expected behaviour is changed. Instead of routing to `recipes/:id` the url updated to `recipes;0=1`

PRE URL : localhost:4200/recipes

```
<!-- Here index is of type number -->
<a
  style="cursor: pointer"
  [routerLink]="[index]"
  class="list-group-item clearfix"
>Some Link</>
```

When I click on this link, the page i was expected to route to was `localhost:4200/recipes/1`;
Instead the URL updates to `localhost:4200/recipes;0=1`.

However converting the index to string by using `toString()` or `+ ''` fixes the problem.